# How do I return multiple columns without consider Na values and group by other columns name in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, variables

```
mexico <- c(1,2,5,1,NA,1)
argentina <- c(2,2,2,2,NA,2)
italy<- c(NA,10,10,10,NA,10)
spain <- c(NA,NA,11,11,11,11)
england <- c(5,NA,10,NA,NA,12)
germany <- c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,10)

Data_Risk = data.frame( Mexico, Argentina, Italy, Spain, England, Germany)

Data_Risk
```

gives

```
 mexico     argentina italy spain england germany

1      1         2    NA    NA       5       1
2      2         2    10    NA      NA      NA
3      5         2    10    11      10      NA
4      1         2    10    11      NA      NA
5     NA        NA    NA    11      NA      NA
6      1         2    10    11      12      10
```

in this case, I need no consider NA cases, for this reason I tried this

```
Data_Risk <- as.data.table(Data_Risk)
my_c <- !apply(Data_Risk, 1, is.na)[,1]
my_L <- Data_Risk[1]
as.data.frame(my_L)[my_c]
```

The results:

```
  Mexico Argentina England Germany
1      1         2       5       1
```

in this case, I need not only that it considers a row, but all of them.
Moreover group by  each row need to be put in new columns without consider 
the values, so the final tables have to look like this:

```
var1           var2          var3       var4     var5    var6
mexico    argentina       england    germany     null    null
mexico    argentina         italy       null     null    null 
mexico    argentina         italy      spain  england    null
mexico    argentina         italy      spain     null    null
spain      null             null       null      null    null
mexico    argentina         italy      spain england  germany
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to look at `which(!is.na(Data_Risk), arr.ind = T)` and spread that to wide form, substituting the `col` variable with `order(col)`, and adding a `colnm` column to use as the value.var in the spread-to-long (`dcast`) process.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

nms <- as.data.table(which(!is.na(Data_Risk), arr.ind = T))

nms[, .(colnm = names(Data_Risk)[col], col = paste0('var', order(col)))
    , by = row] %>% 
  dcast(row ~ col, value.var = 'colnm')

#    row   var1      var2    var3    var4    var5    var6
# 1:   1 mexico argentina england germany    <NA>    <NA>
# 2:   2 mexico argentina   italy    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
# 3:   3 mexico argentina   italy   spain england    <NA>
# 4:   4 mexico argentina   italy   spain    <NA>    <NA>
# 5:   5  spain      <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
# 6:   6 mexico argentina   italy   spain england germany
```

Equivalent `dplyr` code:

```
library(dplyr)

nms <- as.data.frame(which(!is.na(Data_Risk), arr.ind = T))

nms %>% 
  group_by(row) %>% 
  mutate(colnm = names(Data_Risk)[col],
         col = paste0('var', order(col))) %>% 
  spread(col, value = colnm) %>% 
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some question of what is wanted but if what you want is to replace each NA with the following non-NA separately in each row, the following gives a matrix of that form:

```
library(zoo)
t(apply(Data_Risk, 1, na.locf0, fromLast = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    5    5    5    1
[2,]    2    2   10   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    5    2   10   11   10   NA
[4,]    1    2   10   11   NA   NA
[5,]   11   11   11   11   NA   NA
[6,]    1    2   10   11   12   10
```

or if what you want is to move the NAs in each row to the end:

```
t(apply(Data_Risk, 1, function(x) c(na.omit(x), rep(NA, sum(is.na(x))))))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    5    1   NA   NA
[2,]    2    2   10   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    5    2   10   11   10   NA
[4,]    1    2   10   11   NA   NA
[5,]   11   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[6,]    1    2   10   11   12   10
```

or equivalently:

```
t(apply(Data_Risk, 1, function(x) "length<-"(na.omit(x), length(x))))
```

Comment: Thanks for you support!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `apply` row-wise, find out non-NA indices, replace them with column names and append the remaining ones with `NA`.

```
t(apply(Data_Risk, 1, function(x) {
    inds <- which(!is.na(x))
   c(names(Data_Risk)[inds], rep(NA,ncol(Data_Risk) - length(inds)))
}))

#        [,1]         [,2]     [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]     
#[1,] "mexico" "argentina" "england" "germany" NA        NA       
#[2,] "mexico" "argentina" "italy"   NA        NA        NA       
#[3,] "mexico" "argentina" "italy"   "spain"   "england" NA       
#[4,] "mexico" "argentina" "italy"   "spain"   NA        NA       
#[5,] "spain"  NA          NA        NA        NA        NA       
#[6,] "mexico" "argentina" "italy"   "spain"   "england" "germany"
```

Wrap the `apply` in `data.frame()` if you want the final output to be data frame.

Comment: Thanks four your support!