# how to select 1 of several variables with the same prefix?

Tags: r, join

Continuing my previous question [How do I return multiple columns without consider Na values and group by other columns name in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55476013/how-do-i-return-multiple-columns-without-consider-na-values-and-group-by-other-c)

```
Mexico_01 <- c(1,2,5,1,NA,1)
Mexico_02 <- c(3,NA,2,0,4,1)
Argentina_01 <- c(2,1,5,2,NA,2)
Argentina_02 <- c(2,3,NA,2,2,2)
Italy<- c(NA,10,10,10,NA,10)
Spain_01 <- c(2,NA,4,6,8,11)
Spain_02 <- c(3,4,NA,11,11,11)
England <- c(5,NA,10,NA,NA,12)
Germany <- c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,10)
Data_Risk = data.frame( Mexico_01, Mexico_02, Argentina_01, Argentina_02, 
Italy, Spain_01, Spain_02, England, Germany)

Data_Risk <- as.data.table(Data_Risk)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
all_variable <- as.data.table(which(!is.na(Data_Risk), arr.ind = T))
all_variable [, .(colnm = names(Data_Risk)[col], col = paste0('var', 

order(col))) , by = row] %>%  dcast(row ~ col, value.var = 'colnm')
```

gives

```
row      var1         var2         var3         var4     var5     var6     
var7
1:   1 Mexico_01    Mexico_02 Argentina_01 Argentina_02 Spain_01 Spain_02  
England

2:   2 Mexico_01 Argentina_01 Argentina_02        Italy Spain_02     <NA>     
<NA>

3:   3 Mexico_01    Mexico_02 Argentina_01        Italy Spain_01  England     
<NA>

4:   4 Mexico_01    Mexico_02 Argentina_01 Argentina_02    Italy Spain_01 

Spain_02

5:   5 Mexico_02 Argentina_02     Spain_01     Spain_02     <NA>     <NA>     
 <NA>

6:   6 Mexico_01    Mexico_02 Argentina_01 Argentina_02    Italy Spain_01 
 Spain_02

 var8          var9
 1: Germany    <NA>
 2:    <NA>    <NA>
 3:    <NA>    <NA>
 4:    <NA>    <NA>
 5:    <NA>    <NA>
 6: England Germany
```

for this case, I need  only consider a single variable of all variables with the same prefix, for example: instead of mexico_01 or mexico_02 only select mexico.

so the final tables have to look like this:

```
var1           var2          var3       var4     var5    var6
mexico    argentina       england    germany     null    null
mexico    argentina         italy       null     null    null 
mexico    argentina         italy      spain  england    null
mexico    argentina         italy      spain     null    null
spain      null             null       null      null    null
mexico    argentina         italy      spain england  germany
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can split the column with `tstrsplit`, get the `duplicated` ids based on 'row', 'V1' column, assign those elements in 'V1' to `NA` and then do the `dcast`

```
out[, c("V1", "V2") := tstrsplit(colnm, "_")]
i1 <- out[, .I[duplicated(.SD)], .SDcols = c('row',  'V1')]
out[i1, V1 := NA_character_]
out[, V1 := V1[order(is.na(V1))], row]
dcast(out, row ~ col, value.var = "V1")[, row := NULL][]
```

#### data

```
out <-  all_variable [, .(colnm = names(Data_Risk)[col], 
         col = paste0('var',  order(col))) , by = row]
```

Comment: thanks for you support, but do u know how consider only time this variable, I mean, that does not repeat the variable as the final table that I show above.

Comment: @Lectxx7  Can you elaborate a bit about `does not repeat the variable`.  In your final table, I find `england`, 'germany' etc repeating

Comment: I mean, that only considers one variable per row, for example; first row:

Comment: @Lectxx7  I got it, but are you sure the expected output is based on the example because I find some values are not matching

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the values not is necessary, only consider once for each variable per row

Comment: @Lectxx7  IN that case, the updated code should work.  Can you check?

Comment: thanks again, is it possible that the variables that move on the left, I mean, all variable on the left and "na" on the right. do u know what I mean? like the final table above

Comment: @Lectxx7  We can do that by ordering the rows before the `dcast`

Comment: @Lectxx7  I updated the post with `out[, V1 := V1[order(is.na(V1))], row]` pls check

Comment: thanks again @akrun, is it posible that the variable don´t  consider the last 2 digits instead of not considering "_", because I have several variables with "_"

Comment: @Lectxx7  Probably, you need `sub`, `sub("\\d{2}$", "", names(data))`

Comment: thanks a lot, when you put  out[, c("V1", "V2") := tstrsplit(colnm, "_")] above, we need don't considering the las 2 digits